# How to stop ajax call being triggered several times when using .scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a piece of `jQuery` that allows to me to amend some html on the fly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#target').height() / 2) {
    request = $.ajax({
              // ajax call
            });

       request.done(function(html){
            $(html).appendTo('#target');
       });
  }
}
});
```

So basically when the user scrolls past half way on the element with `id='target'` it triggers with ajax call which gets some new html and gets appended to target.

Also when scrolling up and down around the boundary (the half the height of `target`) can lead to multiple triggers of the call.

Is there a way to only allow one ajax call when it passes half way then it cannot make another call until it passes the new halfway point of `#target` with the appended html?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a state for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let isRequestInProcess = false; // state of request

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    if (
      ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#target').height() / 2) &&
      !isRequestInProcess
    ) {

      isRequestInProcess = true; // change state as in process
      request = $.ajax({
                  // ajax call
                });
      request.done(function(html){
           isRequestInProcess = false; // change state again to false
           $(html).appendTo('#target');
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi I got that part working thanks, one last question, I am loading in elements in batches when appending the html. Instead of saying `when we are halfway down the height of target append these new elements` is there a way to say `once you have displayed 10 elements show 10 more` or something like that? Because if I `target` is 20  elements long then it is making the call at 10 (halfway point) and when there is only 10 more elements to display it makes sense to call the next lot however if it is 100 elements then it will be called when there are 50 left to display which is overkill! Thanks